# распределение чисел в 2 столбца. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть csv файл с числами разделенные "," и все эти числа находтся в одном столбце. Для удобства дальнейшей работы хочу разделить на 2 отдельных столбца. Но никак не могу понять как это делать. Для string это просто, нужно использовать механизм .str.split(','), но что делать, если все значения числа?

Уже пробовал перевести все числа в string и по известной схеме, но по-моему есть вариант получше.

Пример данных:
"Time, seconds","Series values, dB"
0,-117
0.0001,46
0.0002,-478
0.000300001,2
0.000400001,4
0.000500001,-218
0.000600001,-322

Уже много чего перепробовал. Можете помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто укажите правильный разделитель столбцов `sep=','`, дальше `Pandas` разберётся:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
"Time, seconds","Series values, dB"
0,-117
0.0001,46
0.0002,-478
0.000300001,2
0.000400001,4
0.000500001,-218
0.000600001,-322""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',')
print(df)
```

Вывод:

```
   Time, seconds  Series values, dB
0         0.0000               -117
1         0.0001                 46
2         0.0002               -478
3         0.0003                  2
4         0.0004                  4
5         0.0005               -218
6         0.0006               -322
```

Answer (score 1):

Если используете pandas, то можно так:

```
import pandas as pd

d=pd.read_csv('d.csv',header=None, decimal=',', dtype={'0': float})
d.columns = ['Time, seconds', 'Series values, dB']
print(d)

  Time, seconds  Series values, dB
0             0               -117
1        0.0001                 46
2        0.0002               -478
3   0.000300001                  2
4   0.000400001                  4
5   0.000500001               -218
6   0.000600001               -322
```

Comment: `sep=','` же вроде, какой ещё `decimal` )  И зачем `header=None`, тут же есть нормальный заголовок.

Comment: @CrazyElf по тому что в вашем ответе данные обрезаны, заголовки съехали, вот по этому, если это не нужно, можно убрать.

Comment: Съехавшие заголовки - это всего лишь проблемы копирования табуляций из вывода в ответ. Если сделать `print(df)`, как у вас, то уже ничего не съезжает )  А то, сколько знаков после запятой печатает `Pandas`, регулируется настройками. Если залезть в конкретную ячейку, там всё правильно, я проверял.

Comment: Вы собственно проверяли ваш код с реальными данными? У меня полностью рабочий код с данными. На вашем коде с этими данными `Pandas` вообще ошибку выдаёт, по крайней мере на моём питоне.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да пробовал, ошибок не выдает, если не нужны полные входные данные, все после имени файла можно удалить.